Download csv without direct link (script python)
I am trying to make a python script to download this csv, but the problem is that there is no direct link;
I have tried f12 and go to network and see the link, but even if I put that link, it doesn't let me...
any idea or solution? how can I automate it?
the web is this:
https://echa.europa.eu/es/candidate-list-table
to automate csv downloading
